# Type Mismatch error in Word using VBA to open a file

Tags: vba, ms-word

I wrote some VBA in both Excel and Visio to bulk convert older format files into the latest version, mainly to save space as some files shrink to less then half the size.  Both these programs work fine so I copied one over to do the same in Word but the same code does not seem to work correctly.  Here is a simplified copy of the routine without the looping through folders from Excel that works correctly:

```
Dim File = "C:\Temp\TextFile.xls"
Dim myWorkbook As Workbook

If ((Right(File, 3) = "xls") And (Right(File, 4) <> "~xls")) Then
    ' Open the file
    Set myWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(File)
    ' Save as a xlsx or xlsm
    If myWorkbook.HasVBProject Then
        myWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=File & "m", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled
    Else
        myWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=File & "x", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook
    End If
    myWorkbook.Close (False)
End If
```

And here is the same code converted over for Word that generates a "Type Mismatch" on the Set myDoc line:

```
HostFolder = "C:\temp2"
Dim File
Dim myDoc As Document
For Each File In HostFolder.Files
    If ((Right(File, 3) = "doc") And (Right(File, 4) <> "~doc")) Then
        Set myDoc = Documents.Open(File, False, True, False)
        If myDoc.HasVBProject = True Then
            myDoc.SaveAs FileName:=File & "m", FileFormat:=wdFormatXMLDocumentMacroEnabled
        Else
            myDoc.SaveAs FileName:=File & "x", FileFormat:=wdFormatXMLDocument
        End If
        myDoc.Close (False)
NextFile:
    End If
Next
```

I have tried the same line without the additional options but same result.  I tried also creating another Word application and opening it from there but also same result (plus I shouldn't have to since I'm already in word).  What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: Apparently Word doesn't have a default property that it reads from the variant "File" and I needed to use File.Path.  Once that was done it seems to work correctly.  Not sure why Excel and Visio both have no problem with it.  Either way the correct line is:

```
Set myDoc = Documents.Open(File.Path, False, True, False)
```

Also to get rid of compatibility mode add this right after:

```
myDoc.Convert
```

Then save it like above.

Comment: Works fine for me (with a fix for the first line) so there's something else going on not related to the code you posted.

Comment: `Dim myDoc As Variant` and set a breakpoint on `If myDoc.HasVBProject...`, run the code, check the type of `myDoc` in VBE `Locals` window.

Comment: When hasVBProject =true then Extension has to end with m

Comment: @BigBen I tried to shorted my code too much.  I actually do a Dim File followed by For Each File In Folder.Files.  I updated my code.  Problem still is the same, type mismatch on the Set Doc line.  Updated post.

Comment: @Ike You are correct, I shortened down the code and copy/pasted too much.  My actual code adds the m.  Example updated.

Comment: @taller  I tried as a variant and same. I never get to the HasProject line.  Locals says that myDoc is "Variant/Empty".  If I set it as Document then its Document in the locals window.  If I just define as Dim myDoc then it's "Variant/Empty".   Same error every time.

Comment: @TimWilliams I cannot figure it out. I can manually open these Word documents. They are very old, probably Word 2010 vintage, but I figured if I can manually open them and save as docx then I should be able to batch convert them but that doesn't seem to be the case

Comment: Figured it out.  For whatever reason I needed to use File.Path and not just File like in the other conversion programs.